# Symfony auto resolve controller without registering as a service

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using Symfony 3 and I'm looking at how to inject services into my controllers via the constructor. I don't want to register each controller as a service.

Diving into the code I have overridden the default ControllerResolver's instantiateController method with the following:

```
protected function instantiateController($classname) {
    return $this->container->get($classname);
}
```

Note: I have passed in the container within the constructor and I am using Symfony's dependency injection component.

However this throws the error:

> You have requested a non-existent service
>   "controllers\hellocontroller"

I thought auto resolving was built into the latest version of Symfony DI. I was wondering if anyone could show me what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: if you don't want register each controller as a service, just don't do that and retrieve your services with the auto-injected DIC (to do that you can extends `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller` or implements `Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface` + `use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareTrait` trait)

Comment: Any specific reason why you want the benefits of registering controllers as services, but not actually register the controllers as services? Seems really odd to me.

Comment: @Oldskool it just seems like unnecessary work. Especially if I have lots of controllers.

Comment: Well, your question is pretty much the answer to why it isn't unnecessary work. You can also bundle all your controller services in a single file and include that (at least when using YML). You either need to register the services or create a "custom" work-around, like @Federico suggested. Either way, it requires additional work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but I don't wish to change my application code. I am trying to refactor the framework to utilize Symfony, specifically the routing and dependency injection components.

Comment: You may be misunderstanding the autowiring capability of the Symfony dependency inject container.  Autowire applies to service dependencies.  You cannot autowire the service itself.  You will need a service definition entry for each controller.  No easy way around it.

Comment: Thanks @Cerad. It looks like I'm going to have to use my existing dependency injection container. I'll leave this question open to see if Symfony adds support for this in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Symfony 3.3 you can register controllers as services via [PSR-4 autodiscovery](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/05/07/how-to-refactor-to-new-dependency-injection-features-in-symfony-3-3/#4-use-psr-4-based-service-autodiscovery-and-registration).

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true

    App\:
        resource: ../{Controller}
```

Comment: Thanks, this will make things a lot easier.

Comment: Happy to help! Symfony 3.3 is getting very matured in DI. Checkout the post I linked for more. There are like 4 new awesome features.